# Why does sudo xhost throw an error on openSUSE, but su -c xhost does not?

Tags: sudo, opensuse, su, xhost

Here are some things that work:

```
xhost
su -c xhost
su -c su `logname` -c xhost
```

Here are some things that do not work:

```
sudo xhost
sudo su `logname` -c xhost
sudo runuser -l `logname` -c xhost
sudo -u `logname` xhost
```

Those each threw the following error: `access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect`

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or how I can use the `xhost` command in a script that my users will most likely be running with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when sudo is used on openSUSE, the DISPLAY environment variable is not set. This ended up working for me:

```
sudo DISPLAY=`ls /tmp/.X11-unix | tr 'X' ':' | grep -o ":[0-9]" | head -n 1` su `logname` -c xhost
```